# Alerts above nav bar issue

Tags: html, css

We currntly have the rails alerts taking space above the nav bar which forces the nav bar to always be below the alert box even if there is no alerts shown. Where do we find the css for the alerts 
Shown below is an image of the inspection of the page showing the alerts above the nav, we need them below.
thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
</head>
  <div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">404Book</a>


      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><%= link_to 'My Profile' ,profile_path(current_user)%></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %></a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>


  <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your HTML is not correct. You are closing a div in the nav element. Move the `</div>` below the `</nav>` closing tag.